# C# SharePoint GetUserEffectivePermissions() only returns null

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm attempting to evaluate the permissions of all users on a SharePoint site.
Currently, I have this code:

```
foreach (User member in web.SiteUsers)
{
     BasePermissions res = web.GetUserEffectivePermissions(member.LoginName).Value;
     if (res != null) Console.WriteLine(member.Id + " : " + member.Title + " : " + res.Has(PermissionKind.AddAndCustomizePages));
     else Console.WriteLine(member.Id + " : " + member.Title);
}
```

This is just trying to see specifically, whether the users have the ability to Add and Customise Pages.

The problem is that res is always null when I know for a fact many of the users I'm iterating through have that permission.
Why is it null and is there a better way to test permissions?

Please Note: I cannot run this on the server, it must adhere to the CSOM (Client Side Object Model).

Comment: I currently have the same issue ? Have you found a solution on that ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error. I needed to add clientContext.ExecuteQuery() after GetUserEffectPermissions().